# Delete ACF repeater field row on Front End

Tags: ajax, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to delete row from front end. This is what i did :

HTML :

```
<?php $row = get_row_index(); ?>
<tr data-rownum="'. $row .'">
  <td>
    <span class="deletecontrat iconfont_d" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Effacer ?">r</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

AJAX.JS

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.deletecontrat', function() {

    $rownumjs = $(this).parent().parent().data("rownum");

    jQuery.post(             
            ajaxurl,
            {
                'action': 'mon_action',
                'param': $rownumjs
            }
            ,
            function(response){
                    console.log(response);
            }
    );

});
```

FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
function add_js_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri().'/custom/js/ajax.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script('script', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js_scripts');




function mon_action() {

    $param = $_POST['param'];

    delete_row("field_5c8fa4201b65f", 1, $post_id);

    echo $param;
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mon_action', 'mon_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mon_action', 'mon_action' );
```

So in my console i get response :

- **1** for the first row
- **2** for the second row

and so on…

I assume that my code working, but now i can't or i don't know how to execute my delete function…
I have read [this](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/delete_row/), but nothing happen.

What am i doing wrong ?

(I hope i'm cristal clear because english is not my language.)

Answer (score 1):

You have `1` hardcoded as the row number in `mon_action()`.

It should be `delete_row( 'field_5c8fa4201b65f', (int) $_POST['param'], $post_id );`

Comment: Hum yes but it was for a test and i've tried with


`delete_row( 'field_5c8fa4201b65f', $param, $post_id );`



It doesn't work either

Comment: How are you getting `$post_id`?

Comment: But just with `function mon_action() {
echo "<script>console.log('the message function is called');</script>";
 die();
}` i have no response in ma console log

Comment: That wouldn't work as you're expecting it to. The rest of your code works fine.